# Mathematical term for a hollow cylinder?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there an advanced mathematical/geometry term for a "hollow cylinder/pipe"? If I just use the term cylinder, it evokes a solid, like a dowel.  I would like to properly describe a toilet paper roll type of cylinder.

Thank you!

Comment: I think that in relatively advanced mathematics "cylinder" usually means the surface. "Sphere" is the surface; when you want the solid you say "ball". In elementary school blocks cylinder is the solid. Probably for Archimedes too. Just make sure your reader understands what you mean in what you're writing.

Comment: Thank you Ethan, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to check out [cylindrical shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder#Right_circular_hollow_cylinder_(cylindrical_shell))

Comment: I checked out your link, and I think the term "open cylinder" is closest to what I was striving for. Thank you for your input.

Comment: If I hear "open cylinder", I would guess it means a cylinder without one or both circles at the ends.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wolfram Alpha, the best mathematical term is [cylindrical shell](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cylindrical%20shell&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Solid%22%2C%20%22CylindricalShell%22%7D). Other names for the same thing include "pipe" and "hollow cylinder" as the OP mentions. Personally, I prefer "tube".

To clarify, the term "cylinder" is ambiguous, as explained in detail by [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html). In its most common usage, it refers to a right circular cylinder, which is a solid. Other kinds of solids are also called cylinders, one possible difference being that the end planes are not at right angles to the axis.

However, in some mathematical contexts, "cylinder" refers to just the surface of such an object, which is less ambiguously called a "cylindrical surface". (Wolfram points out that topologists do not consider this a true "surface", adding to the confusion.)

The OP asks about a "hollow cylinder", "pipe", and "toilet paper roll". That suggests to me the correct term is "cylindrical shell", which is a solid, rather than "cylindrical surface" (or "cylinder" in that meaning).

Comment: Those cylindrical shells have a positive width. I _think_ the OP wants the name for a cylindrical surface. At least that's what they thanked me for in response to my comment. "cylindrical shell" is suggested in another comment, so this answer really adds nothing to the five year old discussion.

Comment: A cylinder is a surface. Hollow cylinder makes no more sense than hollow sphere.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think the OP wants the name for a solid, or else the question would be the term for the surface of cylinder, not a hollow one, but I've updated my answer to provide both options.

Comment: @JohnDouma The term "cylinder" is quite ambiguous, but in common non-mathematical contexts (and sometime in math, too) it usually refers to a solid, not a surface. Certainly with the term "hollow cylinder" the OP is using "cylinder" to refer to a solid.

Comment: @OldPro Not in mathematics. It always refers to a surface. That's really basic geometry. A cylinder is a classic example of a 2-manifold.

Comment: @JohnDouma See reference book Zwillinger, D. (Ed.). _CRC Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae, 32nd ed._ which says ["we also apply the word _cylinder_ to the solid enclosed by the surface"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/CRC_Standard_Mathematical_Tables_and_For/ZIJhsqo9O7MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22we+also+apply+the+word+cylinder+to+the+solid+enclosed+by+the+surface+generated+in+this+way%22&pg=PA257&printsec=frontcover)